# When I try to set up an array in python reading in data from a text file I am encountering a mysterious syntax error

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I run this piece of code I am getting a syntax error and I do not know what is wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNosW.png)

Comment: You should add your code to the question rather than use an image. You seem to be missing a closing }.

Answer (score 0):

```
well, absorption = np.loadtxt('python test file.txt', 
                              skiprows=3, 
                              usecols=(1,7), 
                              dtype={
                                  'names': ('Well', 'Abs'), 
                                  'formats': ('U3', 'f4') , 
                            unpack = True)
```

Here is the code, I have already tried a closing } but it still gave me the same error